# Getting Hello World BlackBerry widget working

Tags: blackberry, widget, ota

I am having trouble getting Blackberry HelloWorldWidget.zip widget to work.

I compile with widget builder (bbwp.exe 2.0.0.18). I get all INFO and WARNING. No errors. Signing tools shows no signing required. I can load in simulator (9780) and run. I can load OTA to Bold 9700.

However when I click the application icon on BlackBerry, it does not open or show any error message.

I tried adding these lines to the XML file, but to no avail,

```
<access subdomains="true" uri="*"/>
<feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an possible solution

When I click on .cod file in bin/StandardInstall, I get 6 items to sign.
When I click on .cod file in bin/OTAinstall, I get no items to sign.

The two cod files are identical sizes and created at the same time.

However, Why might this be occuring?

Comment: I took the cod file in stanadardinstall, signed it. Then renamed it as a zip, unzipped the component .cod files & copies them into the /OTAinstall library. This worked.